# Replace NaN value in table from dataframe without changed other values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, nan

I created pivot table from dataframe used below code

```
table = pd.pivot_table(df_table, values=['KPI Amount Convert to USD'], index=['Customer Nick', 'Customer',
                                                                             'Customer Name', 'BSO Name', 'BSO Comment',
                                                                            'Pay Date, Recovery action, No pay schedule reason '],
                       columns=['Range'], aggfunc={'KPI Amount Convert to USD': np.sum}, margins=True,
                       margins_name='Grand Total')
```

it works great, but some value are NaN (other are regular number)

when I used

```
table = table.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
```

the NaN value are empty, BUT some value are changed to 3.0176e+06, even before it was 3017601.99.

Do you have any idea how to replace NaN value, but preserve int format of other?

thanks for your advice

Comment: Any sample data to reproduce the problem?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is the `dtype` (data type) of the column, or more exactly on the underlying numpy array. I assume that in your `table` dataframe, the column containing NaN values have a floating point type (float64).

If you replaced NaN with 0., all would be fine, but if you want to write an empty string there, Pandas change the `dtype` to `object`.

BTW, 3.0176e+06 is just a different representation of 3017601.99 but I would assume that the value has not changed. Simply pandas uses different representation for `np.float64` type columns and `object` type columns.

You can ask it to use the default `str` conversion for float values in `object` columns by setting the relevant option: `pd.set_option('display.float_format', str)`

Demo:

```
>>> pd.set_option('display.float_format', None)                # reset option
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[3017601.99], [np.nan]], columns=['A'])
>>> df
            A
0  3017601.99
1         NaN
>>> df1 = df.fillna('')
>>> df1
            A
0  3.0176e+06
1            
>>> pd.set_option('display.float_format', str)      # set the option
>>> df1
           A
0 3017601.99
1           
>>> df.loc[0,'A'] == df1.loc[0,'A']
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try 
table = table.fillna('')

Comment: Yes, still same problem, but when I used table = table.fillna(0), the other values are correct

Comment: I think it is just display formatting. I checked the datatype before and after using fillna and it has not changed.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

```
  table = table.fillna('-')
```

or

```
  table = table.fillna(0)
```

Comment: This work but why it doesn't work for  table = table.fillna(' ')?

Comment: @Winter Serge beat me to it... `pd.set_option` is what you need if you want to change how it looks.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue of formatting - basically, when a column in in a given type, the numbers are shown in a certain way.

If your column has only floats (so numbers and np.nan fit in that), it will display things one way.

If your column has floats and strings (numbers and '') then the column dtype is set to "object" and it displays various things differently, such as large floats/ints

This is why df.fillna(0) works (0 is also a float so dtype remains float) but df.fillna('') creates the same display change.

The actual value does not change, eg:

```
df.loc[2,0]
> 3017601.990
df.fillna('').loc[2,0] == df.fillna(0).loc[2,0]
> True
```

Comment: So if I want to see whole number and not 3.0176e+06 I have no other option than use table = table.fillna(0)?